# How to force the height of image inside left <td> follow the height of right <td> automatically?

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design

For example, inside a table I have an image inside a td, and some text at right td:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/></td>
  <td>test1<br/>test2<br/>test3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want the height of image follows the height of its right td automatically:

When the right td is shorter than the image, the image is scaled down:

[image]

When the right td is taller, the image is scaled up:

[image]

Is there any way to do this? I tried:

```html
<table style="position:relative;height:auto;">
  <tr style="position:relative;height:auto;">
  <td style="position:relative;height:auto;"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" style="position:relative;height:auto;"/></td>
  <td style="position:relative;">test1<br/>test2<br/>test3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

but I can't get my desired result.
```

Comment: Do you need to use a table - they should not be used for layout purposes - only for tabular data (which this doesn't seem to be)

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) CSS rule to 100%

Like this:

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" style="max-height:100%;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be easy to do it with jQuery than plain CSS. 
You can try below solution if that helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="first"><img
                src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/65756ce7bab4d76ac10456972dd9f21d?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" /></td>

            <td id="second">test1<br />test2<br />test3<br /> test1<br />test2<br />test3<br />
                test1<br />test2<br />test3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var h1 = $("#second").css("height");
        console.log(h1);
        $("img").css("height", h1);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```